# What is the pkcs11 equivalent of NCryptSecretAgreement and NCryptDeriveKey functions

Tags: openssl, cryptography, pkcs#11, cng, ecdh

I have an application running on Linux which needs to generate derived key with ECDH. I get ephemeral public key and KDF parameter and need to return derived key data.

This will be matched against secret and derived key generated on windows server with ephemeral private key and smart card public key with same KDF parameter. Windows uses `BCryptSecretAgreement` and `BCryptDeriveKey` APIs.
But the derived data is not matching.

I have an application running on Linux which needs to generate derived key with ECDH. I get ephemeral public key and KDF parameter and need to return derived key data. I am using `C_DeriveKey` API to generate the derived data(of type `CKO_SECRET_KEY`) in one shot with peer public key, KDF params and private key stored on smart card.

Linux:

```
    CK_ECDH1_DERIVE_PARAMS scdh_params;
    memset(&ecdh_parms, 0, sizeof(ecdh_parms));
    ecdh_parms.kdf = CKD_SHA256_KDF;
    ecdh_parms.ulSharedDataLen = 0;
    ecdh_parms.pSharedData = NULL;
    ecdh_parms.ulPublicDataLen = buf_size;//peer public key size
    ecdh_parms.pPublicData = buf; // peer public key

    mech.pParameter = &ecdh_parms;
    mech.ulParameterLen = sizeof(ecdh_parms);

    rv = p11->C_DeriveKey(session, &mech, privateKey, newkey_template, n_attrs, &newkey);`
```

This will be matched against secret and derived key generated on windows server with ephemeral private key and smart card public key with same KDF parameter. Windows uses `BCryptSecretAgreement` and `BCryptDeriveKey` APIs.
But the derived data is not matching.

Also I can derive secret by setting
`ecdh_parms.kdf = NULL;`
But not able to derive data using secret with `C_DeriveKey` API as it is throwing `CKR_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID`.

What is the equivalent of `BCryptSecretAgreement` and `BCryptDeriveKey` in pkcs11? I was thing `C_DeriveKey` can do both functionality but it is not working.